# Internal RTL8723bs wifi works in live usb, but not after installing

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

It’s weirder than the title makes out. Wi-Fi worked from the live USB, but not after installing Ubuntu. So, I went back to the live USB to see if I could work out why, but it now doesn’t show up there either!

A further wrinkle. I wiped the drive and then left it for a day. When I tried again, Wi-Fi worked on the live USB! But after installing, again, it did’t work.

In either setup, I can `modprobe` the `r8723bs` module and `dmesg` says it has loaded, but it doesn’t create the network interface.

Examining `dmesg` from before (when Wi-Fi works) and after (when it doesn’t), the difference is this line is present when Wi-Fi does work, but is absent when it doesn’t:

`rtl8723bs: acquire FW from file:rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin`

The file is present on the live and installed `fs`. I don’t know why it isn’t loaded though.

I have done a lot of reading and just don’t know where to look next. Any suggestions?

Comment: See if there are any firmware loading errros:  dmesg |grep -i firm   That hardware is on the sdio bus, so does not show up with lspci or lsusb. What kernel are you using? I thought the 4.15 kernel networking worked, but it took the 4.19 kernel for bluetooth to work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. And what is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: James are you sure it has a SDIO wifi card?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Pretty sure: https://www.realtek.com/en/products/communications-network-ics/item/rtl8723bs

Comment: Hi, I'm trying the 19.10 live usb. I've updated my description with some more relevant info.

Comment: If "acquire FW..." was the last 8723 reference from dmesg, then the auth never happened.  Do you see access points to connect to? Have you tried to connect to yours?  What is the driver version number (from dmesg)--I assume it's 4.3.5.5_12290.2140916_BTCOEX20140507-4E40 since it's doing a firmware load.

Comment: Hi, no that's not the last message. When I see that message the system then proceeds to connect to my ap no problem. All works as it should. After I install though, that message never appears in dmesg. Could this be a signing/secureboot issue? I have installed fedora for the moment, as the WiFi works fine if I boot from the shim efi.